# Trouble installing luasocket/lfs using luarocks

Tags: lua, luarocks, luafilesystem

I installed luarocks and now I am trying to use it to install luasocket.

My command is

```
luarocks install luasocket-2.0.2-3.win32-x86.rock
```

and the response I get is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\luarocks\command_line.lua:186: bad argument #1 to 'require' (string expected, got table)
```

The line of code in `command_line.lua` giving trouble is

```
if commands[command] then
    local cmd = require(commands[command])
```

and putting trace writes in the code reveals that `commands[command]` is indeed a table, of length zero.

This sort of fundamental runtime error is way beyond anything a Lua novice can be expected to fix. Any suggestions?

*Edit*

Turns out it's not just luasocket. I get the same problem with

```
luarocks install luafilesystem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is caused by having an old LuaRocks 2.0.10 installation that I wasn't aware of. It was put there by a failed attempt to install LuaDist-Batteries.

Solution here: https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/issues/714 .